# Match portion of a capture group with Perl Regex

Tags: regex, perl, capture-group

I have a datafile with a structure such as:

```
FNAME:LNAME:USERNAME
```

I am trying to go through and check if the format is valid for each line of this data file by using regex.

The way I want to do it is as follows except I am unsure how to set up the expression for the username portion.

```
if(/([A-Z]):([A-Z]):_______/)
```

$1 will give the entire first name, $2 will give the entire last name.  the username is comprised of the first letter of the first name and the first four of the last name. I am unsure how I could check this with capture groups.  Is there a way for me to check only a portion of $1 and $2 without making variables outside of the regex expression itself?

Comment: How do you handle John Doe and Jane Doe?

Comment: What if lastname has less than 4 characters?

Answer (score 3):

How about something like

```
/^([A-Z])[A-Z]+:([A-Z]{4})[A-Z]+:\1\2$/
```

- `([A-Z])` First caputure group. Contains the first character from the `FNAME`
- `[A-Z]+` Matches the rest characters
- `([A-Z]{4})` Second characters. Contains `4` characters from `LNAME`
- `[A-Z]+` Matches the rest characters
- `\1\2` Contents of first and second capture group forms the `USERNAME` part

Comment: Yeah that's not a bad idea.  Was trying to avoid doing something like that unless needed though.  Is there no way to match only a portion of a capture group?

Comment: @Bagelstein By reducing the caputure group all together. See here only those characters that are required are captured in groups